# After the game, we went out to eat, went to the movies, and then went home. Is it a simple or compound sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english

> After the game, we went out to eat, went to the movies, and then went home.

Is that a simple or compound sentence?

Comment: Welcome! Can you share some of your thoughts on why it might be either simple or compound? (Also, just to simplify things off the bat, try leaving out the dependent clause "after the game"; it doesn't affect the answer (and doesn't require a comma after it)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, I have confused about the last thing which is "and then went home". Is it a simple sentence?

Comment: If you define a compound sentence as one that contains a coordination of at least two independent clauses, then strictly speaking it's a simple sentence containing a coordination of not clauses but three verb phrases: "After the game, we [went out to eat], [went to the movies], and [then went home].

Comment: Thanks! I asked because we want to encourage people to do some research and thought before asking. [This page](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/compound-sentences.html) might help explain things. This sentence has three verbs, but it doesn't have more than one independent clause. It's a simple sentence (though it has a complex verb).

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I'm not so well in english grammar rules. Hope you will help me again if required.

Comment: Complex verb? There's no such thing. The core structure consists of the subject "he" plus a coordination of three predicates/verb phrases. "After the game" is not a clause but a preposition phrase functioning as a temporal adjunct.

Comment: Or you can view it as a compound sentence with various repeated parts (like _and_ and _we_) deleted by rule from a basic sentence _We went out to eat, **and we** went to the movies, and then **we** went home._ The infinitive phrase _to eat_ can also be considered a subordinate clause, but that's not necessary here; it can be treated as a prepositional phrase just as easy.

Comment: I suppose the presence of the subordinate clause "to eat" might mean that technically it's a complex sentence.

Comment: '[W]e went out to eat, went to the movies, and then went home.' would traditionally be labelled as having a 'compound **predicate**' {see [Nordquist](https://study.com/learn/lesson/compound-predicate-examples.html#:~:text=Lesson%20Summary-,A%20compound%20predicate%20occurs%20in%20a%20sentence%20when%20multiple%20verbs,what%20the%20subject%20is%20doing.)}. Two _we_'s omitted: '[W]e went out to eat, Ø went to the movies, and then Ø went home.' (Ø = deleted subject)

Comment: @JohnLawler and BillJ As part of the main clause "we went out to eat," I would say that the infinitive "to eat" is being used as an adverb, to modify "went."  Of course, I'm aware that one might also classify it as a clause instead of an adverbial phrase: does this mean that *the sentence could be either simple or complex* depending on how you choose to designate its components?  That makes OP's question more complex (ha ha) than it seems at first!

Answer (score 0):

> After the game, we went out to eat, went to the movies, and then went home.

I have added brackets for ease of viewing:

> After the game, we [went [out to eat]], [went [to the movies]], and then [went [home]].

This sentence could be considered a simple sentence consisting of a compound predicate forming a series.  We could omit the repeated *went* from the last two predicates and reword the sentence.

> After the game, we went out to eat, to the movies, and then home.